Github Actions pipeline terminates after 10 minutes with a timeout
I am trying to run a CI/CD pipeline through GitHub Actions. If it finishes within 10 minutes - there are no problems. But as soon as it runs for 10 minutes it gets terminated with an error:
Run Command Timeout
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

If I re-run failed jobs - the process takes less than 10 minutes and is usually successful.
I tried adding
timeout-minutes: 100.


I tried dividing the job into separate granular steps.
I tried adding for loop to print out a simple message while the job is running.
Here's my original yml file:
name: Build And Deploy (GCP)

   
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - development
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Deploy the latest changes from dev to prod
    timeout-minutes: 100

    steps:
      - name: Checkout the files
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Deploy to main server
        uses: easingthemes/ssh-deploy@main
        env:
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_KEY_DEV }}
          REMOTE_HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST_DNS_DEV }}
          REMOTE_USER: ${{ secrets.USERNAME_DEV }}
          TARGET: ${{ secrets.TARGET_DIR_DEV }}/web 

      - name: Executing remote ssh commands using ssh key
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST_DNS_DEV }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME_DEV }}
          key: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_KEY_DEV }}
          script: |
            sudo apt -y update
            sudo  apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-venv
            export PYTHON=$(which python3)
            yarn install           
            cd ${{ secrets.TARGET_DIR_DEV }}
            cp ./server/docker-compose.prod.yml -f .
            sudo docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up frontend -d --build
            sudo docker system prune -a -f


Which step times out? The timeout might be configured in the action used by the step. Workflow timeout defaults are much higher than 10 minutes.

In this version of the code it's the step "name: Executing remote ssh commands using ssh key"
But I separated it into 3 different steps: yarn install, python and docker-compose
And it doesn't matter which step is active as soon as the process crosses 10-minute mark it gets terminated.

appleboy/ssh-action has an input parameter command_timeout, which defaults to 10m. You can adjust the timeout by setting a higher value.
I also recommend pinning the version of the action, instead of using @master, or else it might break randomly when something changes:
      - name: Executing remote ssh commands using ssh key
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST_DNS_DEV }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME_DEV }}
          key: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_KEY_DEV }}
          command_timeout: 20m
          script: |
            # Your script

